# node js routing with ejs res.render does not work, but res.send does

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I am setting up the environment for a node js app.
But the views/ejs files are not being rendered. If i do:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

res.send('Something');
});
```

This works. But, if I do(having an index,ejs file):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){

res.render(index);
});
```

It does not work, I get "index is not defined" on the cleint side in the web, but no error in the command line.

Here is the app.js:

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));



app.get("/", function(req, res){

 res.send('Something');
});

app.get("/", function(req, res){

res.render(index);
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log(`Express is running on port ${port}`)
})
```

IS there something wrong with the app.set parameters, or has something changed? I am following a tutorial which might be out dated, but checking the docs, I do not see an issue.

So, what is wrong here, is there a new way to do the routing with ejs? I know partials are gone now. Does this mean no ejs files at all anymore, and if so, how is it supposed to be done now? By rendering an html file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not a pro of express but here index is not defined because you write it like a variable. Try using something like this

```
res.render(path.resolve(__dirname + "/views/index"));
```

Comment: @Frank
Oh wow, this rendered it. I swear I am watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gnsO8-xJ8rs and he used it exactly as I have posted it and it works.o0. Thanks